# Why is my code in phaser 3 not updating from the timeout function?

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework, game-development

I've been trying to solve this all day. At first i thought this was a scopes issue but it's not. I'm trying to scale my object, with my interval. The interval works, and when i test it with console.log() it updates to the new value. But my object isn't scaling?

```
leftScale = 1;
setInterval(() => {
    leftScale++;
    console.log('Check: ' + leftScale);
 }, 2000);



leftPlatform = this.physics.add.staticGroup();
leftPlatform.create(250, 450, "left_platform").setSize(leftScale * 250).setScale(leftScale, 1);
```

If i just change the leftScale to a value without the interval it works, but i need to use the interval. I'm confused, because the interval is working, and the setScale works. But both of them together do not. Any ideas?

Comment: every time the value of `leftScale` changes, `.setSize(leftScale * 250).setScale(leftScale, 1)` isn't executed for you - you need to do that yourself (inside the setInterval callback)

Comment: it is recommended to use [Tweens](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/category/tweens) for animations